# I am having trouble with my code, when I compile the code it says "cannot find symbol."

Tags: debugging, javac

```
public class Percentage
{

   public static void main(String args[])
   {

      int tenPercentOff;
       int price = 100;
      double price2 = 100.00;
      tenPercentOff (price);
      tenPercentOff (price2);
   }

    public static void tenpercentOff(int p)
   {

      double newPrice = p * .90;
      System.out.println("Ten percent off");
      System.out.println("New price is " + newPrice);
   }

    public static void tenPercentOf(double p)
   {

      double newPrice = p * .90;
      System.out.println("Ten percent off");
      System.out.println("New price is " + newPrice);
   }
}
```

Comment: `tenPercentOff` vs `tenpercentOff` vs `tenpercentOf`

Comment: Try this `public class Percentage {
 public static void main(String args[]) {

      int priceInInt = 100;
      double priceInDouble = 100.00;
      tenPercentOff(priceInInt);
      tenPercentOff(priceInDouble);
   }

    public static void tenPercentOff(int p) {

      double newPrice = p * .90;
      System.out.println("Ten percent off");
      System.out.println("New price is " + newPrice);
   }

    public static void tenPercentOff(double p) {

      double newPrice = p * .90;
      System.out.println("Ten percent off");
      System.out.println("New price is " + newPrice);
   }
}`

Answer (score 2):

method `tenPercentOff` is undefined, as a side note this is really bad, you should name your methods/variables more consistently (thus avoiding this kind of problems)

Answer (score 0):

Your calling method's  wrong

```
   tenPercentOff (price);
```

should be

```
tenpercentOff (price);
```

and

```
  tenPercentOff (price2);
```

should be

```
tenPercentOf(price2)
```

And you should really work on java naming conventions  another point is use a IDE,which saves you alot of time

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are callind different function.
Java is case sensitive language. So `tenPercentOff()` and `tenpercentOff()` are two different function in java.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
public class Percentage
{

   public static void main(String args[])
   {

      int tenPercentOff;
       int price = 100;
      double price2 = 100.00;
      tenPercentOff (price);
      tenPercentOf (price2);
   }

    public static void tenPercentOff(int p)
   {

      double newPrice = p * .90;
      System.out.println("Ten percent off");
      System.out.println("New price is " + newPrice);
   }

    public static void tenPercentOf(double p)
   {

      double newPrice = p * .90;
      System.out.println("Ten percent off");
      System.out.println("New price is " + newPrice);
   }
}
```

- Java is case sensitive So tenPercentOff and tenpercentOff is not same
- Second method call was having wrong method name (tenPercentOff -> tenPercentOf)

Answer (score 0):

Java is case sensitive, your method with int has a small p for percent and your method with double argument is a single f in Of